# Browser "Move to" command isn't working

Tags: google-chrome, shortcut

I have two monitors and use Chrome. I went to select the command to moves the window to the other monitor, and it only shifts the window over a bit, and doesn't show up at all on the other monitor. Same thing going the other way, the window shifts over a little, but doesn't show up at all on the other monitor. I also created a shortcut for the action, same thing happens.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking and on which Apple product you face this issue.